# Combine multiple online cloud storage services into one drive?

Tags: cloud-storage

Cloud storage services, such as Dropbox, Google Drive, and SkyDrive, all provide a limited amount of free online storage.

Is there any way, preferably for OS X or Linux, to combine them into a single mounted directory?

Ideally, a solution would distribute the data similar to how a RAID-5 system works.

Comment: what platform do you want this to work on?

Comment: @tapped-out Linux or OS X.

Comment: You could try a union mount, but that wouldn't handle writes properly.

Comment: as Bob said, the biggest problem with something like this would be writing files to it. each service has different amounts of space, different upload size restrictions, etc. i don't know of a program or script that could do something like this, and it would be pretty difficult to write one